# Bot Framework Composer: iterating over an array of object (in json) produces invalid output

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm calling http service which returns an array of objects in json.
Inside Bot Framework Composer, I'm using For each loop to iterate over the array.
For each item of the array, bot needs to ask user a question.
Text of the question comes from received array of items.

Running in bot emulator, bot asks first question, but does not ask any subsequent questions.
How to make it ask a question for each returned array item?

JSON returned from http service:

```
 "questions":[
        {
            "question_id":"78jha873_q1",
            "text":"What is question 1?"
        },
        {
            "question_id":"78jha873_q2",
            "text":"What is question 2?"
        },
        {
            "question_id":"78jha873_q3",
            "text":"What is question 3?"
        },
        {
            "question_id":"78jha873_q4",
            "text":"What is question 4?"
        },
        {
            "question_id":"78jha873_q5",
            "text":"What is question 5?"
        }
    ]
```

[Bot Composer design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnmIh.png)

[Bot Emulator runtime - asking questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgYRi.png)

Bot Composer code:

```
{
              "$kind": "Microsoft.Foreach",
              "$designer": {
                "id": "49MVnl"
              },
              "index": "dialog.foreach.index",
              "value": "dialog.foreach.value",
              "actions": [
                {
                  "$kind": "Microsoft.TextInput",
                  "$designer": {
                    "id": "yr2RbY"
                  },
                  "disabled": false,
                  "maxTurnCount": 1,
                  "alwaysPrompt": false,
                  "allowInterruptions": false,
                  "prompt": "${TextInput_Prompt_yr2RbY()}",
                  "property": "turn.userAnswer"
                },
                {
                  "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
                  "$designer": {
                    "id": "ehxqn9"
                  },
                  "activity": "${SendActivity_ehxqn9()}"
                }
              ],
              "itemsProperty": "dialog.my_api_response.reasoning.questions"
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:
Within For-each loop, inside Bot Asks activity, under Other tab, set "always prompt" property to true.